# Adding a foreign key with Db2 of IBM

Tags: sql, db2, foreign-keys

I am testing Db2 and I have kinda touble with foreign key :

```
CREATE TABLE "JDZ89139".orders  ( OrderId integer not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) , 
                                BookingId INTEGER,
                                DateFrom DATE NOT NULL,
                                DateTo DATE NOT NULL,
                                Price FLOAT,
                                Paid BOOLEAN,
                                PRIMARY KEY (OrderId),
                                FOREIGN KEY (CustId) REFERENCES "JDZ89139".customers(CustId),
                                FOREIGN KEY (AptName) REFERENCES "JDZ89139".apartments(AptName));
```

return me the error :

> Status: Failed Error message Column, attribute, or period "CUSTID" is
>   not defined in "JDZ89139.ORDERS".. SQLCODE=-205, SQLSTATE=42703,
>   DRIVER=4.25.1301

Actually jokely speaking I agree that "CUSTID" is not defined in "JDZ89139.ORDERS" because this is a bit the point of foreign key XD joke apart, how could I actually do for make it work ?

Comment: Please read the documentation for functionality you are using. A FK does not declare its referencing columns. It declares that subrow values in its already-declared referencing columns appear in the already-declared referenced columns.

Comment: Your table has no column CustId, so it can't be used by the fk.

Comment: I used MySql / MariaDB syntax, which syntax should I use ? where can I find precise and clear documentation about Db2 for foreign key ?

Comment: you probably need custid and appname columns in the orders table.  simple. or complex subrow referencing in already declared referencing columns.  difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key specifies that a *column* in one table refers to the primary key of another table.

The key point is that the column must be defined in the referencing table -- as well as the referenced table.  The definitions must use the same type.

So you need to declare `CustId` and `AptName` as columns in order to have a foreign key reference:

```
CREATE TABLE "JDZ89139".orders  (
    OrderId integer not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) , 
    BookingId INTEGER,
    DateFrom DATE NOT NULL,
    DateTo DATE NOT NULL,
    Price FLOAT,            -- SHOULD BE NUMERIC/DECIMAL
    Paid BOOLEAN,
    CustId INT,             -- guessing the type is INT
    AptName VARCHAR(255),   -- or whatever the type is
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderId),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustId) REFERENCES "JDZ89139".customers(CustId),
    FOREIGN KEY (AptName) REFERENCES "JDZ89139".apartments(AptName)
);
```

This speculates on the types.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example 11 from [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) documentation, it shows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_ACT
     (EMPNO       CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
      PROJNO      CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
      ACTNO       SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      EMPTIME     DECIMAL(5,2),
      EMSTDATE    DATE,
      EMENDATE    DATE,
      CONSTRAINT EMP_ACT_UNIQ UNIQUE (EMPNO,PROJNO,ACTNO),
      CONSTRAINT FK_ACT_PROJ FOREIGN KEY (PROJNO)
                             REFERENCES PROJECT (PROJNO) ON DELETE CASCADE
     )
     IN SCHED
```

you need to define column name first and then specify it as the constraint.
In your specific case, you can do it like this (skipping some of the columns)

```
db2 "create table customers(customerid int not null primary key)"
db2 "create table orders(orderid int not null generated always as identity, 
                         custid int not null, 
                         constraint fk_cust_id foreign key (custid) references customers(customerid))"
```

Comment: I already created customers and orders table thank :) can you tell me more about what is ON DELETE CASCADE and SCHED ? and then my FK will be (in the example) EMPNO, PROJNO and ACTNO or FK_ACT_PROJ or both ?